# Can the sketch look in Balsamiq be turned off?

Tags: wireframe, balsamiq

We're looking into wireframing solutions and Balsamiq is a good candidate.

How do you turn off the sketchy look?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now in 2.2. I just found it.

Go to View > Skin > Wireframe Skin